# Need help creating a raw socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7. I have tried everything and it is not connecting. The error I get is:

```
Socket could not be created. Error Code : 10013 Message An attempt was 
    made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

I am making a ping.

```
def doOnePing(destAddr, timeout):
    icmp = socket.getprotobyname("icmp")
    # SOCK_RAW is a powerful socket type. For more details see: 
    # http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw
    # Fill in start
    # Create Socket here
    try:
        #mySocket = socket.socket(2, 3, 1)
        # the public network interface
        HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

        # create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
        mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
        mySocket.bind((HOST, 0))

        # Include IP headers
        mySocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

        # receive all packages
        mySocket.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

        # receive a package
        print mySocket.recvfrom(65565)

        print ('Connected by', destAddr)
    except socket.error , msg:
        print ('Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + 
              ' Message ' + msg[1])
    #Fill in end
```

Comment: Are you running your script as root? Creating raw sockets is usually a privileged operation.

Comment: You'll have to run this script as an administrator. I'm pretty sure you want to pass `icmp` as the third argument to `socket.socket()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your script as a privileged user. The `root` user on Linux would be appropriate.

Comment: I think they're on Windows, otherwise their script wouldn't be using `socket.ioctl`.

Comment: i am on Windows, sorry